# xquery- how to select entire text within a div containing some plain text as well as other text within p tag+links/images

Tags: xquery

Given below is some HTML code corresponding to a div in a web page--

```
<div id="1">
    Text #1
    <p> Text #2 </p>
   <img src="test.jpg" />
    Text #3
    <a href="http://google.com"> Text #4 </a>
    <a href="http://www.bing.com"><img src="bing.jpg" /> </a>
    Text #5
</div>
```

What will be the Xquery expression that retrieves the text

```
Text #1 Text #2 Text #3 Text #4 Text #5
```

from the expression above? The sequence in which links/images occur within the main div may differ, I just want to extract the text matter within that div...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
/data()
```

and change the path step (here: only root) as needed. `data()` recursively returns all contents within a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, one can use:

```
string(/)
```